# Deadlock on closing a pipe while another thread reads this pipe?

Tags: macos, pipe, deadlock

I'm having a deadlock on closing a pipe:

```
close(myPipeFD);
```

Another thread, the reading thread, is in a blocking read state from this exact same pipe:

```
ssize_t sizeRead = read(myPipeFD, buffer, bufferSize);
```

Could it be the cause of such deadlock? I thought that `read` would have immediately returned `sizeRead == 0`? Should I emit an interruption in this reading thread?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on osx with named pipe. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to close a file descriptor when another thread may be using it, for several reasons.

As you've discovered, some system calls which can block waiting on the file descriptor may behave in unexpected ways if that file descriptor is closed.

But there are other problems. Let's suppose that the first thread closes a file descriptor *just before* a second thread enters a `read()` call on it. Let's also suppose that a third thread happens to be opening a file or a socket at the same time. The new file descriptor will get the same number as the one that was just closed. The second thread will read from the wrong file descriptor!

In general, you need to make sure that only one thread is operating on a file descriptor at a time. Threads should "own" file descriptors. You can pass ownership from one thread to another, but only one should own each at a time.

If you need to cancel operations, you need to use non-blocking I/O and things like `select()` for when you need to block waiting for data. Furthermore, you need to include a cross-thread communication channel (e.g. pipe) in the `select()` call which will be the mechanism by which one thread submits a request to the other to close one of its file descriptors.

You should also look into Dispatch I/O or asynchronous mechanisms like run-loop driven `NSFileHandle`.